# invalid literal for int() with base 10 ValueError File "game.py", line 1705, in BINARY_Cube_ResultList

Tags: python

File "game.py", line 1705, in BINARY_Cube_ResultList

ValueError

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

code:

```
def BINARY_Cube_ResultList(self, npcVNUM, listText):
        # ResultList Text Format : 72723,1/72725,1/72730.1/50001,5  이런식으로 "/" 문자로 구분된 리스트를 줌
        #print listText

        if npcVNUM == 0:
            npcVNUM = self.currentCubeNPC

        self.cubeInformation[npcVNUM] = []

        try:
            for eachInfoText in listText.split("/"):
                eachInfo = eachInfoText.split(",")
                itemVnum    = int(eachInfo[0]) -1705 line
                itemCount   = int(eachInfo[1])

                self.cubeInformation[npcVNUM].append({"vnum": itemVnum, "count": itemCount})
                self.interface.wndCube.AddCubeResultItem(itemVnum, itemCount)

            resultCount = len(self.cubeInformation[npcVNUM])
            requestCount = 7
            modCount = resultCount % requestCount
            splitCount = resultCount / requestCount
            for i in xrange(splitCount):
                #print("/cube r_info %d %d" % (i * requestCount, requestCount))
                net.SendChatPacket("/cube r_info %d %d" % (i * requestCount, requestCount))

            if 0 < modCount:
                #print("/cube r_info %d %d" % (splitCount * requestCount, modCount))                
                net.SendChatPacket("/cube r_info %d %d" % (splitCount * requestCount, modCount))

        except RuntimeError, msg:
            dbg.TraceError(msg)
            return 0

        pass
```

Comment: You're passing an empty string to `int`, that's not a valid input and generates this error. There must be values of `eachInfo` with nothing before the comma. Add a check or a `try except` for what to do if no input is there. Probably just `continue`.

Comment: Or you can also do a list comprehension on the list considering it contains enough elements, for example: `[x for x in eachInfoText.split(",") if x.isdigit]`

Comment: I am very weak in this. Write code should look like, please